# ASCI chart of discrete time units

Tags: sql, bar-chart, sql-server-2016

**The fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d7d80/6

**The data:**

```
CREATE TABLE schedule
    ([dte] date, [tme] time, [wkd] int);

INSERT INTO schedule
    ([dte], [tme], [wkd])
VALUES
    ('2020/01/01', '17:30', 15),
    ('2020/01/01', '18:00', 15),
    ('2020/01/01', '18:15', 15),
    ('2020/01/02', '17:30', 30),
    ('2020/01/02', '18:00', 30),
    ('2020/01/03', '17:30', 120),
    ('2020/01/04', '17:45', 45),
    ('2020/01/05', '17:45', 30),
    ('2020/01/06', '17:45', 15),
    ('2020/01/07', '18:00', 30);
```

The table consist of three columns: date, time and minutes worked.  Time and minutes worked are always in 15 minute increments (full hour, 15 past, half hour, 45 past).

**The problem:**

I would like to show a simple ASCI utilisation chart showing worked and free periods.  For example for the above data it could look something like:

```
01/01| X XX
01/02| XXXX
01/03| XXXX
01/04|  XXX
01/05|  XX
01/06|  X
01/07|   XX
```

**The attempted solution:**

I've started with the following query:

```
with cte as (SELECT dte,
       tme,
       convert(time,DATEADD(MINUTE, wkd, tme)) as fns
FROM   schedule)

SELECT dte,
       max(case when CONVERT (TIME,{t '17:30:00'}) >= tme 
                 and CONVERT (TIME,{t '17:45:00'}) <= fns then 'x' else null end),
       max(case when CONVERT (TIME,{t '17:45:00'}) >= tme
                 and CONVERT (TIME,{t '18:00:00'}) <= fns then 'x' else null end),
       max(case when CONVERT (TIME,{t '18:00:00'}) >= tme
                 and CONVERT (TIME,{t '18:15:00'}) <= fns then 'x' else null end),
       max(case when CONVERT (TIME,{t '18:15:00'}) >= tme
                 and CONVERT (TIME,{t '18:30:00'}) <= fns then 'x' else null end)
FROM cte
GROUP BY dte
```

While it seems to be working I can already see this approach will be really awkward if I ever had to change the time period I'm looking at or extend it from just one hour to two or more hours.

I'm sure there is a clever trick which could be used to simplify this query.. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to your query, using conditional case statement with `max()` aggregate. I use the underscore instead of space for easier to verify the result

```
SELECT dte,
       MAX (CASE WHEN '17:00' >= s.tme AND '17:00' < DATEADD(MINUTE, s.wkd, s.tme) THEN 'X' ELSE '_' END) +
       MAX (CASE WHEN '17:15' >= s.tme AND '17:15' < DATEADD(MINUTE, s.wkd, s.tme) THEN 'X' ELSE '_' END) +
       MAX (CASE WHEN '17:30' >= s.tme AND '17:30' < DATEADD(MINUTE, s.wkd, s.tme) THEN 'X' ELSE '_' END) +
       MAX (CASE WHEN '17:45' >= s.tme AND '17:45' < DATEADD(MINUTE, s.wkd, s.tme) THEN 'X' ELSE '_' END) +
       MAX (CASE WHEN '18:00' >= s.tme AND '18:00' < DATEADD(MINUTE, s.wkd, s.tme) THEN 'X' ELSE '_' END) +
       MAX (CASE WHEN '18:15' >= s.tme AND '18:15' < DATEADD(MINUTE, s.wkd, s.tme) THEN 'X' ELSE '_' END) +
       MAX (CASE WHEN '18:30' >= s.tme AND '18:30' < DATEADD(MINUTE, s.wkd, s.tme) THEN 'X' ELSE '_' END) 
FROM   schedule s
GROUP BY dte
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a template or procedure of some kind to generate your query. From the question it's not clear if you're running the query directly (manually) in sql server or if there is some kind of app doing it for you against an sql server database. In the first case, you could create a stored procedure to generate the query for you based on the time unit interval (in your case 15 minutes). In the second, you could have the backend of whatever app you're using generate the query.

The general case in pseudo code is

```
// inputs

timeUnit = 15 min
rangeStart = 17:30:00
rangeEnd = 18:30:00

// algorithm
discreteTimes = toDiscreteTimes(rangeStart, rangeEnd, timeUnit) // calculate discrete times between rangeStart and rangeEnd, so in your case 17:30, 17:45, ..., 18:30

query = "..." // up to the start of your case statements
for (i = 1; i < discreteTimes.maxIndex; i++) {
    query += caseStatement(discreteTimes[i-1], discreteTimes[i]) // generate your case statement with these two times
}

query += "..." // the rest of the query after the case statements
```